# How to add 'current location button'(navigation mark) on apple map on Ti.map

Tags: titanium, apple-maps

I am using Ti.map for my titanium iOS/android

As for Android

There is automatically added the current location button

[image]

(I am not sure what this button is called, so I call this 'current location button' for now.

However As for iOS,

current location button is not added automatically.

Is there a way to add this button on apple map??

These are my codes.

```
    var mapView = Map.createView({
        mapType:Map.NORMAL_TYPE,
        userLocation:true,
        region: {latitude:35.699058, longitude:139.326099,    
        latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
        animate:false,
        regionFit:true,
        userLocation:true,
    });
```

---

I read [this](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/blob/master/apidoc/Map.yml) article and found.

```
  -   To use the `userLocation` property in iOS 8 and later, add either the
        [`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW26)
        or
        [`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18)
        key to the iOS plist section of the project's `tiapp.xml` file.
            <ti:app>
                <ios>
                    <plist>
                        <dict>
                            <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
                            <string>
                                Specify the reason for accessing the user's location information.
                                This appears in the alert dialog when asking the user for permission to
                                access their location.
                            </string>
                        </dict>
                    </plist>
                </ios>
            </ti:app>
```

So I add this in my tiapp.xml and prompt alert is shown correctly.

However, still current location button is not appeared.

In default apple map application of iOS, there is current location button (arrow mark) down left.

---

Thanks to comment.

My first idea is wrong. 'userLocation:true' is not related with the button which I called 'current location button'

So I made another button manually and connect Ti.Geolocation.

```
var locationButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        backgroundImage:'/images/check.png',
        right:'15dp',width:'32dp',height:'32dp'
    });
    mapView.add(locationButton);
    locationButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
        Ti.API.info("get current location");    
         if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
            Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
                if (e.error) {
                    Ti.API.error('Error: ' + e.error);
                } else {
                    Ti.API.info(e.coords);
                    mapView.setLocation({
                        latitude:e.coords.latitude, longitude:e.coords.longitude, animate:false,
                        latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enable location services');
        }
    });
```

[image]

Now it works well, thanks for your help.

Comment: That different button is the one you seek. The one on android is native to google maps. So John's answer is actually proper.

Comment: Ah, I see this button is native to only android, right? So I have to make another button by myself that jumps to the current user location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the map you need to set an extra property:

```
require('ti.map').createView({mapType:MapModule.SATELLITE_TYPE, userLocation:true});
```

That should do the trick ;-)

/John

Comment: Thanks for your reply!, I have some questions.

Comment: It will be the SATELLITE_TYPE view. It is impossible to add the currentlocation button to normal map?. Even I add this code userLocation button not appears, MapModule.SATELLITE_TYPE is the typo of Map.SATELLITE_TYPE??

Comment: Thanks giving me the hint, I an figure out how to integrate what I want.

Comment: @whitebear: Yep, you can use whatever mapType you want. It was just the example I copied from in my code. Sorry, I didn't point that out :-)